# How to create this dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a `dict` object, and a `list` containing lists, and want to combine the keys of the dict with the lists from the list, however the result always comes out in a (predetermined) mess.

```
my_dict = {(255,0,0):'red', (0,255,0):'green', (0,0,255):'blue'}
my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

new_dict = dict(zip(my_dict, mylist))
```

As you might guess, this is not the actual data, but it's the method I'm using in my program, I'll post the real dict and list if it's necessary.

What I want is for new_dict to be consistent with the ordering of the items as described above. How can we achieve this?

Comment: `dict`s have no ordering

Comment: They certainly have some behind the scenes ordering, because the result is always the same, but completely jumbled.

Comment: Yes but the behind the scenes ordering is (pseudo) randomized too

Comment: Use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of normal dict.

Comment: I know, my question is about how to make it ordered and consistent with the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an OrderedDict, ordinary dictionaries (`dict`) are unordered.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict = OrderedDict([((255,0,0),'red'), ((0,255,0),'green'), ((0,0,255),'blue')]) #[(key,val),(key2,val2),..]
my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

new_dict = dict(zip(my_dict, my_list))
print(new_dict)

>>> 
{(0, 0, 255): [7, 8, 9], (0, 255, 0): [4, 5, 6], (255, 0, 0): [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dict` is inherently unordered. To preserve the ordering, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).